# Posting a value to php page not sending

Tags: php, html, post

My issue is I am simply trying to check if the inputted value is being passed and echoing the value that is passed.

Despite Copy-Pasting in both HTML and the PHP (The value above it and changing the naming) This one just doesn't want to work.

An error of (below) is showing

```
Notice: Undefined index: ConfirmNewPassword - Line 12 (marked it with a #)
```

I used an 'isset' to confirm that the value isn't being passed however to fix it I don't know. It isn't clear to me WHY is isn't working.

My HTML code:

```
<form action="php/Test.php" method="post">
    <p>Email: </p><input type="email" name="Email" />
    <p>Username: </p><input type="text" name="Username" />
    <p>Password: </p><input type="password" name="Password" />

    <p>New Email: </p><input type="email" name="NewEmail" />
    <p>New Username: </p><input type="text" name="NewUsername" />
    <p>New Password: </p><input type="password" name="NewPassword" />
    <p>Confirm New Password: </p><input type="password" name="ConfirmNewPassword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update" />
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $Email = ($_POST["Email"]);
    $Username = ($_POST["Username"]);
    $Password = ($_POST["Password"]);
    $NewEmail = ($_POST["NewEmail"]);
    $NewUsername = ($_POST["NewUsername"]);
    $NewPassword = ($_POST["NewPassword"]);
    # - $ConfirmNewPassword = ($_POST["ConfirmNewPassword"]);

    echo "Email = " . $Email .
    "<br />Username = " . $Username .
    "<br />Password = " . $Password .
    "<br />New Email = " . $NewEmail .
    "<br />New Username = " . $NewUsername .
    "<br />New Password = " . $NewPassword .
    "<br />Confirm Password  = " . $ConfirmNewPassword;
}
```

This is the code WITHOUT the isset - I've confirmed that $ConfirmNewPassword has no value
Any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I've been looking for a few hours and trying to fix it for another few, to no benefit.

Comment: The commented line the php isn't commented.

Comment: @Letmesee OP just want to mark the line where problem is. Hamedar, your code looks fine, except for the HTML structure. You can debug via `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: And yet the code doesn't work.
When sent to the php page, $ConfirmNewPassword has no value.
Where do i put the var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: Try by using  the `print_r($_POST)` and see what the array is coming. put it in the if condition.

Comment: put it in anywhere you want to output the debug message. Best place is probably after the `if` line

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ That works. The value IS being given to the page. However the echo or that value doesn't work.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That works as well. The value IS being passed.
However echoing the value still does nothing.

Which means when I try to use it, it'll still be empty.

Comment: There is no issue in the code a live demo can be seen here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/igv-uzb

Comment: Thank you @Noor.
I hate that about web developemnt, the code works, just not in testing.

Comment: I don't suppose someone would know why it doesn't work locally? It is the exact same as the lines above it, yet it just doesn't display. I'm happy that it's fixed, but would like to know more about WHY it is like that.

Comment: This works for me locally also..!! I don't know what might possibly be your problem.

Comment: The strange part is, that it all works locally, just that ONE line doesn't.

Comment: Also, @ShivanRaptor what's wrong with the HTML structure?

Comment: error: `<input>` element is not placed within block elements like `<p>` and `<div>`, making unstable layout.

Comment: Of course. I've yet to run the W3C Validator over my HTMl. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question is "It works".

Just not locally.

Thanks to Noor and all others who helped me learn more about debugging methods and also to solve my problem.